# calling a function works in once instance but not another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant figure out for the life of me why the 2nd click the click next button does not trigger roate.

both $slideNumber will have a value of 1 2 3 or 4, and i have used alert to let me know that this is the case.

its basically not triggering the rotate(); in the 2nd one

the click numbers one works perfectly;

```
//Paging + Slider Function
rotate = function () {

    var triggerID = $slideNumber - 1; //Get number of times to slide
    var image_reelPosition = triggerID * divWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide


    //Slider Animation
    $(".image_reel").animate({
        left: -image_reelPosition
    }, 500);
};

//click on numbers (this one works)
$(".paging a").click(function () {
    $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
    $slideNumber = $active.attr("rel");
    rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
});



//click on next button (this one does not work)
$('#next').click(function () {
    var left_indent = parseInt($('.image_reel').css('left')) - divWidth;
    var slideNumberOn = (left_indent / divWidth);
    var slideNumber = ((slideNumberOn * -1) + 1);
    $slideNumber = slideNumber;
    rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="paging">
                <a href="#" rel="1">one</a>
                <a href="#" rel="2">two</a>
                <a href="#" rel="3">three</a>
                <a href="#" rel="4">for</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav">
                <a id="prev" class="active" href="#">prev</a>
                <a id="next" class="active" href="#">next</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you verify that 1) the non-operational instance is being called and that 2) `$slideNumber` holds the correct value?

Comment: Working with global variables is almost always a bad idea. You should pass `$slideNumber` and `divWidth` as parameter.

Comment: By doesn't work do you mean the function doesn't get called?  What does your html for next button look like?

Comment: make a fiddle for that  on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i can confirm that the alert if i alert($slideNumber); it is the number i want 1 2 3 or 4, which is the same value as the first one. added HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the second click function is erroring out part way through.  Try putting `console.log` statements in the beginning of your function.  If you can place them so that one prints and the next errors out, you've found where the bug is.

Comment: perfect found out what the issue was. basically some code was looking for the $active.attr("rel"); as the 2nd click does not have this it would not run

Answer (score 0):

Where are `divWidth` and `$slideNumber` defined inside `#next` click handler? Because of that it throws error and never reaches next statements to execute.

Comment: these are set firther up my code, the the $slideNumber does alert a value i need to happen, in this case it 1,2,3 or 4